# What syntax error do i have in this class?

Tags: python

I am working on a project that requires me to use **str** to print out as an answer. When I run this code, the compiler gives syntax error by pointing out to return statement. I would love to get help to fix this problem.

I tried to removing parentheses around the return code.

```
import random
class Movie:
  def __init__ (self, title, year, drname, cat, length):
    self.title = title
    self.year = year
    self.drname = drname
    self.cat = cat
    self.length = length

  def __str__(self):
     return (self.title + '('self.cat','+ self.year')' +'directed by ' + self.drname + ', length ' + self.length + 'minutes')

#Apollo 13 (Drama, 1995) directed by Ron Howard, length 140 minutes
#It should be printed out as shown above

mv1 = Movie("Apollo 13", 1995, 'Ron Howard', 'Drama', 140)
```

Comment: Always read the full traceback (error message) generated and include it in the question if unsure. The traceback is very kind and pinpoints the column of the incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code states `'('self.cat','+ self.year')'` without a `+`.

Use `'(' + self.cat + ',' + self.year + ')'` instead.

Also, you may want to consider a space between the category and year. If so, use the following:

```
'(' + self.cat + ', ' + self.year + ')'
```

In addition, your `year` and `length` need to converted to a string, for example using `str(self.length)`.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Fan for reminding me about str(self.length). Now my program is working perfectly fine!

Comment: That's definitely what should be done instead, especially given the sheer number of fields being accessed and converted using concatenation. finswimmer's answer should cover how to do that I think.

Answer (score 4):

Beside the other answer answers, I recommend using f-strings (introduced with python 3.6) for string formating:

```
return f"{self.title} ({self.cat}, {self.year}) directed by {self.drname} , length  {self.length} minutes"
```

Answer (score 1):

just a small syntax error, the plus (+) sign is missing in your return statement.

```
 return (self.title + ' (' + self.cat + ', ' + self.year + ') ' + 'directed by ' + self.drname + ', length ' + self.length + ' minutes.')
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should format the returned value of `__str__` using [f-string (PEP498)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
f"{self.title}({self.cat},{self.year}) directed by {self.drname}, length {self.length} minutes"
```

Your code, PEP8 and working:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, title, year, drname, cat, length):
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.drname = drname
        self.cat = cat
        self.length = length

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} ({self.cat}, {self.year}) directed by {self.drname}, length {self.length} minutes"


# Apollo 13 (Drama, 1995) directed by Ron Howard, length 140 minutes
# It should be printed out as shown above    

mv1 = Movie("Apollo 13", 1995, 'Ron Howard', 'Drama', 140)
print(mv1)
```

Output:

```
Apollo 13 (Drama, 1995) directed by Ron Howard, length 140 minutes
```

Comment: I don't understand, and please explain why

Comment: Lines 2 to 10 are supposedly part of the class block – those need indents/spaces too. The error traceback explains it better (try copy-pasting your code and running it).

Comment: Yes you right, I correct this right now, write code snippets with the APP is not convenient.